# Problema con List <byte[]> en Java

Tags: java, lista, byte

Estoy desarrollando una clase que me gestione un archivo. Uno de los métodos obtiene los bytes que forman dicho archivo, los procesa y los devuelve en forma de `List<byte[]>`. Lo que realizo es lo siguiente:

```
public static List<byte[]> archivo2Bytes(String archivo, int datosMaximos){   //Para el caso que estoy desarrollando son 1454, pero esta como variable ya que puede cambiar segun quien lo invoque
    List<byte[]> datos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        //Cargamos todo el archivo en bytes
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(archivo));          
        //Dividimos el archivo en una lista de (bytes.lenght/datosMaximos) filas con datosMaximos bytes por fila (salvo la ultima, que llevara solo los datos necesarios)
        int nPaquetes = (int)Math.ceil((float)bytes.length/(float)datosMaximos);
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<(nPaquetes-1); i++){//En cada iteraccion introducimos datosMaximos bytes, si solo hay 1 paquete, pasamos directos alfinal
            byte[] aux = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, i*datosMaximos, (i+1)*datosMaximos);
            datos.add(aux); 
        }
        byte[] aux = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, i*datosMaximos, bytes.length);  //Esto es para el ultimo paquete (o el unico)
        datos.add(aux);//Tenemos en cada fila de datos los bytes para mandar
        return datos;
    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
        System.out.println("Imposible encontrar el archivo");
        return datos;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Imposible abrir el archivo");
        return datos;
    }        
}
```

Tengo otro método que coge los bytes en forma de lista y los convierte otra vez al archivo:

```
public static void bytes2Archivo(String archivo, List<byte[]> datos){
    try {
        int tamanho = 0;
        for(int i = datos.size(); i>0; i--){
            tamanho = tamanho + datos.get(i-1).length;  //vemos el tamanho de la lista para formar mi byte[]
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanho];
        for (int i = 0; i<datos.size(); i++){
            System.arraycopy(datos.get(i), 0, bytes, i*datos.size(), datos.get(i).length);  //Copiamos todos los datos de la lista a bytes en orden
        }
        //Pasamos los bytes al archivo
        Files.write(Paths.get(archivo), bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Imposible abrir el arqchivo");
    }        
}
```

Si en el método `archivo2Bytes` hago una llamada a `bytes2Archivo` y le paso `byte[] bytes` (haciendo las modificaciones en el otro método) funciona sin ningún problema pero tal y como está escrito arriba obtengo un archivo del mismo tamaño que el leído pero que no son idénticos (probé con un PDF de 75kb). Es posible que sea por la manera que tengo de dividir el byte en la lista?

La modificación que realizo es:

```
public static void bytes2Archivo(String archivo, byte[] datos){
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get(archivo), datos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Imposible abrir o archivo");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras mucho cavilar llegué a la conclusión de que estaba escribiendo mal el archivo ya que en el método:

```
public static void bytes2Archivo(String archivo, List<byte[]> datos){
try {
    int tamanho = 0;
    for(int i = datos.size(); i>0; i--){
        tamanho = tamanho + datos.get(i-1).length;  //vemos el tamanho de la lista para formar mi byte[]
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanho];
    for (int i = 0; i<datos.size(); i++){
        System.arraycopy(datos.get(i), 0, bytes, **i*datos.size()**, datos.get(i).length);  //Copiamos todos los datos de la lista a bytes en orden
    }
    //Pasamos los bytes al archivo
    Files.write(Paths.get(archivo), bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Imposible abrir el archivo");
}        
}
```

Me di cuenta de que la parte entre ** (i*datos.size()) lo único que hacía era desplazarme unas pocas unidades el inicio y al final acababa con un byte de tamaño X con miles de huecos vacíos. Para solucionarlo simplemente fijé como valor el tamaño del primer dato, quedando del siguiente modo:

```
public static void bytes2Archivo(String archivo, List<byte[]> datos){
try {
    int tamanho = 0;
    for(int i = datos.size(); i>0; i--){
        tamanho = tamanho + datos.get(i-1).length;  //vemos el tamanho de la lista para formar mi byte[]
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanho];
    for (int i = 0; i<datos.size(); i++){
        System.arraycopy(datos.get(i), 0, bytes, **i*datos.get(0).length**, datos.get(i).length);  //Copiamos todos los datos de la lista a bytes en orden
    }
    //Pasamos los bytes al archivo
    Files.write(Paths.get(archivo), bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Imposible abrir el archivo");
}        
}
```